# Calling a function within another function (except main())

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

Let's assume I have 2 functions other than the main(), respectively func1() and func2(). Is it possible for me to call func1() in func(2) without declaring it first? Or should I use a pointer to the other function and pass it as an argument? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Always use a prototype to declare your functions. Further, the answer is "yes." And you don't need pointers.

Comment: This would be easy enough to try!  Have you done that?

Comment: The definition also counts as a declaration (and must match any other declaration you already have). So if `func1()` is defined before `func2()` then "yes", but you can't then call `func2()` from `func1()` without a previous declaration for `func2()`.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @ryyker I have tried that, but a statement in my book caused confusion. I thought it might be related to a difference of the version of the C compiler in the book and I am using.

Comment: Reasons to pass a function pointer, are when the function isn't known to the function you are passing it to, such as the callback function pointer passed to `qsort`, or where you might need to make a runtime decision as to which function it should call.

Answer (score 1):

```
_"Is it possible for me to call func1() in func(2) without declaring it first?"_
```

It depends on compiler, but generally this will not work. (see exclusion example at bottom of answer.)

Some scenarios that illustrate:

Scenario 1: Normally will not work as function is being referenced *before* being declared:

```
int main(void)
{
    int ret = func1();
    return 0;
}

int func1(void)
{
    return 1;
}

int func2(void)
{
    return func1();
}
```

Results:

> 9, 15    error: ***implicit declaration*** of function 'func1' is invalid
> in C99. Make sure that you include the function prototype.

Scenario 2: As all required definitions occur in order, this will compile and run without issue:

```
char func1(void)
{
    return 1;
}

char func2(void)
{
     return func1();
}

int main(void)
{
    char ret = func1();
    ret = func2();
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

Compiles and runs with no problem because both functions are *defined before* being called (both `func2()` called from `main()` *and* `func1()` called from `func1`)

Scenario 3: The best way is always to pre-declare functions using prototypes either in same file *before* functions are called or in a header file that is #included in any source file that uses them.   This clears up any potential problems, especially  for those that inherit the code for maintenance:

```
int func1(void);
int func2(void);

int main(void)
{
    int ret = func1();
    return 0;
}

int func1(void)
{
    return 1;
}

int func2(void)
{
    return func1();
}
```

Regarding your comment:

> *"...a statement in my book caused confusion, I thought it might be related to a difference of the version of the C compiler in the book and I am using."*

Could be:  Per comment below, pre-standard C function definitions are supported by some modern compilers (eg `gcc`) thus would compile scenarios 1 & 2 without issue if functions complied with the [default function definition](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-C.html);  eg:

```
int func1(void)
int func2(void)
```

Comment: Nit: `func1` and `func2` satisfy the default declaration, so compilers that still support this (i.e. gcc) will have no problem with this code.

Comment: @dbush - I edited my post with scenario references so I could have you clarify.  You are saying the `gcc`  will compile scenario 1 & 2 without error or warning?  And I am not sure what you mean by default declaration.  (  `int func(void)` ?  how about `char func(void)` ?)

Comment: Pre-standard C would implicitly declare a function as `int func()` if it's used without a declaration. gcc still supports this, and version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 18.04) compiles it with just a warning.  Not sure about newer versions.

Comment: @dbush -  Just to avoid this special case then, I will edit my answer to non-default prototypes.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Okay i got to try scenario 2 I would never do it like that in a million years, but I'd assume it would work .. interesting !

Comment: Now I'm confused, I ran scenario 2 without a problem. How ever you write "Scenario 2: This will also never work..."

"Results: Compiles and runs with no problem" .. :)

Comment: @Sorenp - Apologies, I have edited since you first looked at it, to address question OP asked, in particular _"to call func1() in func(2) without declaring it first"_, which I did not have in the first version.  Also, incorporated content to address _dbush's_ comment below this post.  I missed changing the statement that scenario 2 still did not work.  It is changed now.

Comment: @ryyker No worries man, just thought I had lost it .. hah :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it:

```c
    void func2(int code);     // forward declaration

    void func1(const char* str)
    {
        func2(str[0]);        // a call to a declared function
    }

    void func2(int code)      // the callee
    {
        printf("code: %d\n", code);
    }
```